# WordPress Latest News Page Showing Custom Fields From All News Stories

Tags: wordpress

I have my own custom WordPress theme and I am building out the 'Latest News' section at the moment. I have a custom field for my page header image and alt tag for each page on my site, I am using the following code to display those custom fields on each page:

```
<section class="page-heading">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <img src="<?php the_field( 'header_image' ); ?>" alt="<?php the_field( 'main_header_image_alt_tag' ); ?>">
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</section>
```

Which works fine. But on my 'Latest News' page all the custom fields from all the news stories (posts) are being displayed, so for example if I have 3 post displayed per page then I am getting 3 images and 3 alt tag displayed.

In my settings I have my 'Posts Page' set to 'Latest News'.

Is there a way I can only have 1 image and 1 alt tag displayed and not all 3?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I've added an image to better explain... The images that span the screen are from the news stories and not the custom field for the 'Latest News' page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question, but you want your first post show the image and the rest not?

I guess you have to write something like this:

```
<section class="page-heading">
<php $show_first_image = true; ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if($show_first_image): $show_first_image = false; ?>
           <img src="<?php the_field( 'header_image' ); ?>" alt="<?php the_field( 'main_header_image_alt_tag' ); ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks vvc. It's hard to explain ... I have a custom field for a header image which is available for all pages on my site, but on my 'Latest News' page - if I have 3 posts set per page (in the reading settings) - the header images from all the individual posts will display instead of just the one for the 'Latest News' page. So if I had 10 posts per page set (in the reading settings) 10 images would appear. I don't want this to happen, I only want the header image for the page to display, not for all the posts.

Comment: I've added an image to try and explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem, your latest news is also a Page (post type), which has the header image.

Your index file/archive is like this:

```
<?php
get_header();
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        // your latest news * 3.
endwhile;endif;
get_footer(); ?>
```

the problem is, got its items loaded before the get_header(), where your header image will be showed.

What you do is something like this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$page = get_query_var( 'pagename' );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'page', 'pagename' => $page ) );
get_header(); // in the get_header() you will probably have the <section class="page-heading">

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;

if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        // your latest news * 3.
endwhile;endif;
get_footer(); ?>
```

I hope this is your answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by creating a new template for my news page and using WP_Query inside that template to bring in the latest news stories. I also unset 'Posts Page' in my reading settings as that's what was causing all the issues.

I'm not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing things but it worked for me.

VVC, I appreciate your help and effort.

```
<!-- WP Query Arguments -->
                                <?php

                                    $args = array(
                                        'page_id' => '103'
                                    );

                                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                ?>
                                <!-- End WP Query Arguments -->

                                <!-- WP Query loop -->
                                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>

                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <h2>No posts to display</h2>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <!-- End WP Query loop -->


                                <!-- WP Query Arguments -->
                                <?php

                                    $args = array(
                                        'post_type' => 'post',
                                        'posts_per_page' => '5'
                                    );

                                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                ?>
                                <!-- End WP Query Arguments -->

                                <!-- WP Query loop -->
                                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="news-story">
                                    <div class="news-heading">
                                        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                        <p class="publish-date"><strong>Posted on:</strong> <?php the_time('j M, Y'); ?></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="site-button-light-blue">Full Story <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></p>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>

                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <h2>No posts to display</h2>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <!-- End WP Query loop -->
```